# OSRM doesn't show actual route while plotting from osrm-backend JSON response

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

While trying to test routing using OSRM Demo server I sent GET request with the following url:

http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/90.4007354,23.7936502;90.3925568,23.7746739?steps=true

When I plot the intersections on a web map with OpenStreetMap tiles in the background I get the following route.:

[image: issue]

But when I use the same cordinate in the [OSRM Demo Server's front-end](http://map.project-osrm.org/) I get the following route:

[image: osrm_frontend]

I have also check that the JSON response from the OSRM Demo Server's front-end which is the same as the response from the url I requested. From the first screenshot we can see that the while routing the flyover is being ignored and the starting and the ending point of flyover are being connected with a straight line when plotted but that is not the case for the OSRM Demo Server's front-end. What am I doing wrong? Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that you plot only the intersections, whereas the OSRM Demo Server plots the whole route.

To plot the whole route, use the geometry element in `routes[0]` in the JSON. The route is encoded using [Google's polyline algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=en).

If you want the route as GEOJSON linestring instead of the encoded polyline, add `&geometries=geojson` to your request.